# How to color specific parts of the bash prompt?

Tags: macos, bash, colors

I am working on a macbook OSX and I am administering some VMs inside my machine. I often make mistakes because all prompts have the same color and type, so I want to differentiate them.

First of all, I want to make `root` account appear in red color because it's a danger by itself!

Secondly I want to be able to color specific IP addresses which belong to my servers, for example "mywebserver.local" (whose address is inside /etc/hosts) and "192.168.54.1".

What I am using right now is :

```
green=$(tput setaf 2);
yellow=$(tput setaf 3);
reset=$(tput sgr0);

PS1='\['"$green"'\]\u\['"$reset"'\]@\['"$yellow"'\]\h:\W\$:\['"$reset"'\] '
```

which only partially does what I want. How do I enter conditions ?

Comment: Look for "PS1" (and ...2, 3, 4)  and also "PROMPT_COMMAND" in http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/abs-guide.html for some tips.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you may want it to be:

```
[ $USER = root ] && PS1="\033[0;40;1;91[ root > ]\033[0;1;94m " || {
    HOST=`hostname`
    if [ $HOST = 'mammothpc_prehistoric' ] ; then
        PS1=...
    elif [ $HOST = 'progueing_alone' ] ; then
        PS1=...
    elif [ $HOST = 'guru_pro_server' ] ; then
        PS1=...
    else
        echo 'Error 404 : no such errors found.'
        PS1=... 
}
```

Instead, by the way, you can also set some color variable and further assign the whole scheme to `PS1`:

```
PS1="$FG[ $USER@$HOST ] : $reset"
```

Comment: tbh, I don't see it working.

Comment: @RobDel This MUST work. Otherwise you have overridden it or have not executed. Also, you have to have your key rc files synced among devices. This is too simple script not to be working. Also, check that you have changed '...'s to something else, aswell as `[ $HOST = ... ]`. Also, try checking `echo $HOST` after assignment. One more reason for fail may be that you have mistyped.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but a great guide that not only describes what I want to achieve but also lots of other usefull stuff: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-customize-your-bash-prompt-on-a-linux-vps